# How to compare two file names

Tags: files, delete

I want to compare two files in a folder and delete the number in the name which is the smaller of the two.

For instance, say the names were `yearMonthDay.txt`. I want to compare which is a smaller number and `sudo rm` it.

I know I can get the numbers via:

```
find *txt | awk -F'[_.]' '{ print $1}'
```

How then next should I compare it? Using system variables? I actually haven't used shell variables before.

Comment: You can set variables, for example `var1=$(command-to-print-filename-1)` etc and then compare the sizes in an `if` command. But you can also sort the files with `sort` and select the first file with `head` or the last file with `tail` and that way decide what to keep and what to remove.

Comment: @sudodus, thanks, I think I got it: eval $(printf "rm file_"$(find *txt | awk -F'[_.]' '{ print $2}' | sort -r | tail -1)".txt")

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make something like the following:

I made a directory with some files with 'normal' date-like names, one file with a space in the name (makes you need quoting) and one file with a new-line in the name (can cause problems, if the commands that you use assume that new-lines separate files).

```
$ find
.
./20210710.txt
./20200131.txt
./20210611.txt
./2020?0131.txt
./20201131.txt
./2020 131.txt
```

The following command line uses `stat` to help the `find`-list of txt-files,

```
$ find -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%N' {} \;
'./20210710.txt'
'./20200131.txt'
'./20210611.txt'
'./2020'$'\n''0131.txt'
'./20201131.txt'
'./2020 131.txt'
```

Now sort it (can be done without removing the extension)

```
$ find -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%N' {} \; | sort
'./20200131.txt'
'./20201131.txt'
'./2020 131.txt'
'./2020'$'\n''0131.txt'
'./20210611.txt'
'./20210710.txt'
```

and select the oldest one (at the top of the list)

```
$ find -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%N' {} \; | sort | head -n1
'./20200131.txt'
```

Now you can remove this file by

```
rm $(find -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%N' {} \; | sort | head -n1)
```

It there is a risk that there would be a space or other special character, you want to quote it (but check carefully that you avoid conflicts with previous quoting)

```
rm "$(find -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%N' {} \; | sort | head -n1)"
```

You can also set a variable, and use that in commands later on in a shellscript

```
#!/bin/bash

find -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%N' {} \; | sort

var1=$(find -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%N' {} \; | sort | head -n1)
echo '---'
read -p "Remove $var1? (y/N) " ans
if [ "$ans" == "y" ]
then
 eval rm "$var1"
fi
```